# How to update the invalid CSRF token message in Symfony 7

Tags: symfony, symfony-translator

Using Symfony 7 with symfony/translation installed, I'm trying to update the message that gets displayed when my login form's CSRF token is invalid.  Currently it reads "Invalid CSRF token." which my users will not have any clue about.

I have my /config/packages/translation.yaml file configured like:

```yaml
framework:
    default_locale: en
    translator:
        default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
        fallbacks:
            - en
        providers:
```

Then in /translations/validators.en.yaml I have:

```
csrf_token:
  invalid: "Wakka wakka"
```

I haven't been able to find any documentation on what exacly the key(s) in the .yaml file should be - what I've got is just a ChatGPT suggestion.

I've cleared my cache, but I'm not seeing the desired message.  What have I misconfigured?

**Update**
As @Jakumi suggested, I updated my yaml file to

```
"Invalid CSRF token." : "wakka wakka"
```

with no luck.

I also tried adding a `security.en.xlf` file in that directory with my translation, and also renaming my yaml file to `security.en.yaml`.  Still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the answer is astonishingly straight-forward: The translation key is the string "Invalid CSRF token." (see [Security component translations](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/d7b9240533a824c80276b848e9415735da203b38/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Resources/translations/security.en.xlf#L29-L32)), in symfony 7 it's this string and in the security "domain". In other versions of symfony it might be somewhere else.

Generally, it's advisable to just **search for the string in the codebase** and if it is translated at all the translation must be in some translation files.

Then, to translate it, [follow the instructions](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#basic-translation). Essentially it just has to be valid yaml, if you're using yaml. As far as I can tell this should be (YAML):

```yaml
"Invalid CSRF token.": "Whatever the translation is."
```

*Some* quotes can be omitted, but I don't want to go into detail.

To check that your translation in works in general, open up a template and add `{{ 'Invalid CSRF token.'|trans({}, 'security')` (the string and the domain might differ!)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm not using .xlf files though - I'm using .yaml.  I'm looking for a way to specify the key in my .yaml file.  Is that possible or do I just have to stick with .xlf?

Comment: I added that to my answer. When the key contains a dot, you can have this kind of structure as you had before with csrf_token.invalid (which was the wrong key), but here the key is a proper sentence (okay, the verb is missing, but you know what I mean), so trying to linebreak after the . would be silly.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  No luck.  I have added an Update to my original post with new stuff I've tried.

Comment: Okay, I tried it locally with a symfony 6. In symfony 6 the string is "The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form." and is located in  validators, so if I put the translation for the string in translations/validators.en.yaml my translation is applied. So I want to suggest again, search in your codebase (more specifically in vendor/symfony/...) for the string you're seeing and you want to change.

Comment: also if your project is live, translations might be cached.

Comment: The problem was two-fold.  1) I wasn't actually invoking the translation.  I had assumed the service would translate automatically once I had the file in place.  2) I had the file named incorrectly/I didn't specify a domain.  Changing my file name to `messages.en.yaml` and actually using the translating service got me what i needed.  Thanks for your help and patienc.

Comment: I suspected, kind of. ;o) Your opening post seemed to imply you were translating successfully in general, but I had my doubts. It's always good to check the assumptions ;o) Glad it works for you now!